# Excel multiple VBA run in different cells and sheets

Tags: excel, vba

my VBA code stoping when i run another VBA. 
i create count timer with 3 buttons, start, stop, reset plus show current time(All VBA)
I need 15 colums with this repeat. The problem start when i click Button1(start count time) or another(no matther) it stops other my codes(Current time, and start,stop,reset buttons of count time) works only button which i click first after run code. How  can i run multiple VBA code that all worked together and did not interfere with each other. 
Sorry for my English.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLIYi.png)
My VBA for start, stop, reset.

```
Public StopIt As Boolean
Public ResetIt As Boolean
Public LastTime
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim StartTime, FinishTime, TotalTime, PauseTime
StopIt = False
ResetIt = False
If Range("C2") = 0 Then
  StartTime = Timer
  PauseTime = 0
  LastTime = 0
Else
  StartTime = 0
  PauseTime = Timer
End If
StartIt:
  DoEvents
  If StopIt = True Then
    LastTime = TotalTime
    Exit Sub
  Else
    FinishTime = Timer
    TotalTime = FinishTime - StartTime + LastTime - PauseTime
    TTime = TotalTime * 100
    HM = TTime Mod 100
    TTime = TTime \ 100
    hh = TTime \ 3600
    TTime = TTime Mod 3600
    MM = TTime \ 60
    SS = TTime Mod 60
    Range("C2").Value = Format(hh, "00") & ":" & Format(MM, "00") & ":" & Format(SS, "00") & "." & Format(HM, "00")
    If ResetIt = True Then
      Range("C2") = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
      LastTime = 0
      PauseTime = 0
      End
    End If
    GoTo StartIt
  End If
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
  StopIt = True
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  Range("C2").Value = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
  LastTime = 0
  ResetIt = True
End Sub
```

**Current time:**

```
Private sub workbook
dim hour as boolean
hour = not (hour)
do while hour = true
doevents
range ("A1") = timevalue(now)
loop
end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple demo code that runs a main loop and services button presses without stopping the main loop ( it still takes away from main loop though )

you have to add code to do other functions

speed up the code by letting cell formulas do all the calculations

on a worksheet, place 1 button and three toggle-buttons

put this code into worksheet also

```
Option Explicit


Dim doFive As Boolean
Dim doSix As Boolean
Dim doSeven As Boolean


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()      ' could be started other ways

    doFive = ToggleButton1              ' this one affects cell G5
    doSix = ToggleButton2               ' G6
    doSeven = ToggleButton3             ' G7

    While True                          ' main demo service loop

        DoEvents                        ' this allows other events to be serviced (like button presses)

        If doFive Then Range("g5") = Range("g5") + 1
        If doSix Then Range("g6") = Range("g6") + 1
        If ToggleButton3 Then Range("g7") = Range("g7") + 1
    Wend

End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

    doFive = ToggleButton1

End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()

    doSix = ToggleButton2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot.